# Perturbation bound for a matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

Let $P$ be a positive definite matrix with $|P_{ij}| \leq R$ and $q$ a given vector with $|q_i|\leq r$. Is it possible to bound
$$
\|(P + xx^T)^{-1}(q + \alpha x) - (P + yy^T)^{-1}(q + \beta y)\|
$$
in terms of $x, y, \alpha, \beta, R, r$?

Comment: I would recommend that you expand the expression using the [Sherman Morrison identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) and see if anything cancels

Comment: In detail, we can write
$$
(P + xx^T)^{-1}(q + \alpha x) - (P + yy^T)^{-1}(q + \beta y) = \\
P^{-1}(\alpha x - \beta y) 
- \left(\frac{x^TP^{-1}q + \alpha x^TP^{-1}x}{1 + x^TP^{-1}x}P^{-1}x - \frac{y^TP^{-1}q + \beta y^TP^{-1}y}{1 + y^TP^{-1}y}P^{-1}y\right).
$$